# Obtener ruta de archivo desde el request.POST en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Quiero obtener la ruta de un archivo que subo mediante un formulario pero al imprimir el campo retorna un tipo `None`.

Mi models.py es este

```
class Insumo(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = models.FileField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

mi forms.py es:

```
class ImportData(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = Insumo
            fields = ['nombre', 'file']
```

mi views.py es este

```
def carga_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formulario = ImportData(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            name=request.POST.get('nombre')
            ruta=request.POST.get('file')
            print (name)
            print (ruta)
            return render(request,"carga_data.html", {'form': formulario})
    else:
        formulario = ImportData()
    return render(request, "carga_data.html",{'form': formulario})
```

y mi template es este:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}                         
        {{form.as_p}}                       
        <input type="submit" value="Cargar Informacion">
</form>
```

y el resultado de los `print(name)` y `print(ruta)` luego de enviar el **submit** es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito la ruta del archivo en vez del `None`

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la ruta del archivo era necesario obtener el `request.FILES` en lugar del `request.POST` el el views.py, asi:

```
def carga_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formulario = ImportData(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            ruta=request.FILES.get('file') #Retorna la ruta del archivo
            print(ruta)

            return render(request,"carga_data.html", {'form': formulario})
    else:
        formulario = ImportData()
    return render(request, "carga_data.html",{'form': formulario})
```